# Associating multiple existing records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm creating an application where one user becomes the account_manager of an account.  What I want to do is to add other users to the account.  A user can only have one account but an account can have many users.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :account_manager, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'account_manager_id'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :account
```

What I'm totally stuck on is having a place where the account manager can either select the user from a dropdown, type in their name, or use some other type of selection.  If I try to do this in console each new user I add replaces the last instead of adding to it.  here is my schema for accounts:

```
create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "account_manager_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
  end
```

I've tried using `collection_select` but I think that is only for :though associations.  I'm also thinking I probably need a join table but I don't know how to set it up.  The thing that is tripping me up most is that I won't be creating new objects, I only want to add existing users to existing accounts.  I'm just looking for someone who can talk through this with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end
```

While in your question, you are writing `has_one`. You can't write `has_many` in one model, and `has_one` in other model. There needs to be `belongs_to` in one model.

Edit:

The model that `belongs_to`, always saves the foreign keys in its table. So `users` would save `account_id` in it. In order to get all the users of an account, you would simply do:

```
Account.first.users # As an account `has_many` users
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I also need a join table to add users to the account?

Comment: You'd need a join table if you have an account has many users, and a user belongs to more than accounts. But in your case, a user can only belong to one account, so you won't need it.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, you can accept it.

Comment: Then does it make sense for me to add account_id to the user model and remove user_id from the account model?  How would I list all the users of an account?